# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'. ts(2322)

Tags: typescript, svelte

The error appears in the VScode console, but my app still works

the error is:

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

The code:

```html
<script lang="ts">
  import { newForm } from 'manzana';
  import { userService } from '$lib/services/user';

  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';
  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  const now = new Date();
  const today = `${now.getFullYear()}-${now.getMonth() + 1}-${now.getDate() + 1}`;

  const { handleSubmit, values } = newForm<{
    name: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    confirmPassword: string;
    username: string;
    birthdate: Date;
  }>({
    initialValues: {
      name: '',
      lastName: '',
      email: '',
      username: '',
      birthdate: today // here the error appears
    },
    onSubmit: async (values) => {

      const birthdate = new Date(values.birthdate).toJSON();

      //here create the user with graphql
      await userService.userCreate({
        name: values.name,
        lastName: values.lastName,
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        username: values.username,
        birthdate
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<div>
  ...
</div>
```

the error appears on line 25

vscode error:
[{
"resource": "/home/michael/Documents/projects/nexus/nexus/src/lib/components/Authenticate/SignUp.svelte",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#0",
"code": "2322",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.",
"source": "ts",
"startLineNumber": 25,
"startColumn": 7,
"endLineNumber": 25,
"endColumn": 16
}]

Comment: you can replace `birthdate: Date` with `birthdate: String`

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have typed `birthdate` as Date type.
However, you have assigned `today` as the value of `birthdate`, and `today` is a string. Try removing the `` around `today`'s value, so that it is no longer a string.

Alternatively, if you expect it to be a string type, then change birthdate to a string type as well.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: could you be more specific? what doesn't work and what error occurs?